Audio not working in my PC
I checked my volume multiple times and troubleshot my speakers, but I couldn’t find a solution. I even restarted my PC, but that didn’t help either.
In my sound settings, the speaker is set to Conexant ISST Audio, even though Realtek is installed. However, I can’t find Realtek anywhere when I try to update my sound driver.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

try to find the exact latest audio driver from motherboard drivers, re-install it and download the software (it sometimes realtek came with software + driver or more), also try another speakers
